Japanese input (Mozc) does not work in Chromium
See subject. in Chromium, Mozc simply does not seem to do anything. Input is still in latin characters. In almost all other programs, Firefox, LibreOffice, search field of xfce start menu... the Japanese input (Mozc) works. But in the program where I need it the most, Chromium, it seems to have no effect at all.
This has been going on for a long time, many different versions and combinations of versions. I am currently on Ubuntu 24.04 and Chromium 126.0.6478.126 (Official Build) snap (64-bit).
Running on Macbook M2.

Welcome to AskUbuntu. This answer is the proper way to solve this out.

@SadaharuWakisaka Not helpful answer, it is from 2012, the necessary packages like ibus-qt4 do not even exist anymore in Ubuntu 24.04.
